# Pre submission form

Tags: javascript

I am new to web-building, I am interested in creating a pre-submission form for new users to a gallery / forum for a ghost group.  Log their inputs when successful.

What I am trying to achieve is.

1. When a new user comes to the the landing page, they are asked for their

   - Username
   - Age
   - Referring site code
2. When they will submit the information, it will check if the username already exists; if they are over 18 and the website code that referred them to the gallery/forum.

I trying to have a members only forum gallery for my ghost group and their friends that are serious.  Not to the  open public.

I want to have a pre form so that if the general searcher stumbles on the page thay cannnot try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at some frameworks such as [stripes](http://stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home) or [struts](http://struts.apache.org/)
which will allow you to have form data posted to servlets and having the framework(and/or servlet) perform validation e.g lookig up to see if a record exists, number > 18 etc.